# Load plugin in dynamic html don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I'm trying to use a carousel thumbnails for my items, however the items are generated by another script, I'm trying to load the plugin for carousel but he can not identify the items.

My Real HTML:

```
<div class="prerecord_main">
   <div id="merch">
   </div>
</div>
```

after prepend by another script:

```
<div class="prerecord_main">
   <div id="merch">
    <div class="product-container"></div>
    <div class="product-container"></div>
    <div class="product-container"></div>
    <div class="product-container"></div>
    <div class="product-container"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery Plugin

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var owl = $(".prerecord_main #merch");
  owl.owlCarousel({
      items : 5
  });

});
```

does not work because it can not read the items "product-container"

Comment: Could you put script enabling owlCarousel put in this second script which generate items? If not you should try to use `$.on()` method on your container.

Comment: Your `owlCarousel` script is finished before the `product-container` elements are created. That is the reason for the error.

Comment: Your `owl.owlCarousel` needs to fire AFTER the new elements are injected into the DOM.

Comment: how to use .on() the container? thanks